# Codeigniter htaccess redirect dropping .php inappropriately

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem right now with my **codeigniter** build. I'm currently migrating a new website on top of a old site.  I want to do 301 redirect with my htaccess file but something is wrong. Normal 301 redirect work properly.

For example:

```
RewriteRule company.php /company [R=301,L]
```

That will go to `domain.com/company`

But any rewrite that has a parameter added to the end doesn't redirect properly. For example:

```
RewriteRule samples.php?searchby=CATEGORY&categoryID=8&sampleID=07-503--004.jpg&page=0 samples/category/custom_color_texture/35/?page=1 [R=301,L]
```

That should go to

```
domain.com/company/samples/category/custom_color_texture/35/?page=1
```

but instead in my URL bar it shows this

```
domain.com/samples?searchby=CATEGORY&categoryID=8&sampleID=07-503--004.jpg&page=0
```

I've been going at this problem for several hours and still haven't figured out any solution.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RewriteRule` directive deals with filesystem paths when you define it in a .htaccess file (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched)

To replace a querystring, you'll need to to use a `RewriteCond` paired with the `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteCond {%QUERY_STRING} searchby=CATEGORY&categoryID=8&sampleID=07-503--004.jpg&page=0 
RewriteRule samples.php samples/category/custom_color_texture/35/?page=1 [R=301,L]
```

You may need to tweak the above code for your particular project